# How to run the Android application in background forever after installing in android phone?

Tags: android

I am working on android application in which there is two text boxes one take IP Address and another textbox take port number and button start service.
this app connected to web server. during installation the App on Android phone when user click start service Button the application connected to webserver and whole application goes in Background...run forever

Comment: impossible, the OS can always kill your service

Comment: You want to do a task in background or want to close the app once you press the start button ?

Comment: you can write broadcasts for ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED, ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL, RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETE etc, then you can start your background services in these broadcast onReceive() method.

Comment: i want to perform the task in background when user click start  button, the app connected to webserver